# Which widget for horizontal scrolling list

Tags: flutter

I would like to horizontally display 5 items at the same time, and I want the possibility to scroll or display a new (next) item each time I press a button on the side.
Which widget can I use to implement it (without package) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think `PageView` suits best for this scenario.

```dart
class TW extends StatefulWidget {
  const TW({super.key});

  @override
  State<TW> createState() => _TWState();
}

class _TWState extends State<TW> {
  final PageController controller = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 1,
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text("Item $index");
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        controller.nextPage(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)

Comment: Is it possible to always show 5 items, and delete the first to add a new one by pressing the button ?

Comment: yap try to play with `viewportFraction:1/5`

Comment: Ok thank you. I remain open to other suggestions.

Comment: Other  widgets like `IndexedStack`, `ListView` ... can be used, but I would choose pageView as current context. You can check [widgets/scrolling](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/scrolling)